# How to create a preview display for jpg, xls, pdf in laravel

Tags: laravel

Should I create a controller file for displaying a file or picture? I used anchor tag for time meantime

Comment: what do you want to do? you can save pictures on db and then you can show each of them on a page

Comment: When I uploaded files or picture,excel, pdf or doc format.  I want to have a preview of them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

/*Image display with preview*/

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/js/dropify.min.js" integrity="sha512-8QFTrG0oeOiyWo/VM9Y8kgxdlCryqhIxVeRpWSezdRRAvarxVtwLnGroJgnVW9/XBRduxO/z1GblzPrMQoeuew==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/css/dropify.css" integrity="sha512-In/+MILhf6UMDJU4ZhDL0R0fEpsp4D3Le23m6+ujDWXwl3whwpucJG1PEmI3B07nyJx+875ccs+yX2CqQJUxUw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.dropify').dropify();

            var drEvent = $('#input-file-events').dropify();
           
           
            var drDestroy = $('#input-file-to-destroy').dropify();
            drDestroy = drDestroy.data('dropify')
            $('#toggleDropify').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (drDestroy.isDropified()) {
                    drDestroy.destroy();
                } else {
                    drDestroy.init();
                }
            });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-3">
  Upload Passport(Max Size 5mb)
 </div>
<div>
  <input id="passport_docs" class="dropify " name="passport_docs" type="file" value="{{ old('passport_docs') }}" data-allowed-file-extensions="pdf doc docx png jpg jpeg" data-max-file-size="5120K" />
</div>

</body>


/*and upload data with formData*/

 var passport_docs = $("#passport_docs").prop("files")[0];

  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("passport_docs", passport_docs);
     
    $.ajax({
    url:"{{route('add-image-ajax')}}", 
    type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: form_data,
   dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {

  }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a laravel code just use ajax and jquery :

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
    url:"{{route('add-image-ajax')}}", 
    type:'POST',
    data: {'_token' : '{{ csrf_token() }}', 'image': response},
    success:function(data){
        console.log('Crop image has been uploaded');
        $('input[name = uploaded_img]').val(data.success);
            $("#previewImgTag").attr('src', response);
    }
    })
```

Comment: <td field-key='filename'> @foreach($file->getMedia('filename') as $media)
     <p class="form-group">
           <a href="" target="_blank">{{ $media->name }} ({{ $media->size }} KB)</a>
                 </p>
                  @endforeach</td>
do I need to delete the anchor tag and add a button for the display??